# When to do conditioning while on Wendler's full body routine?

Tags: weightlifting, conditioning

I'm running Wendler's "doing more with less" set up, as seen here http://www.jimwendler.com/2012/03/doing-more-with-less/

My question is when to fit in conditioning work (I.e. Hill/flat sprints).

Thanks very much.

Comment: Thanks both for your replies! Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Matt Carlson's 5/3/1 variant **Doing More With Less** seems to be structured as

### Lifting, 3 days a week

1. Calisthenics circuit
2. Strength work
3. Conditioning or running

### Running, 2-3 days a week:

1. Calisthenics circuit
2. Running

His non-running, non-calisthenics conditioning work:

> the prowler or some of my conditioning circuits inspired by the CPAT (Candidate Physical Ability Test) involving the prowler, sled and farmers walks afterwards

If you want to do hill sprints, I'd swap them out for that conditioning work without any other changes needed. So you'd do your sprints after the calisthenics circuit and lifting.

Answer (score 1):

Wendler doesn't specify when conditioning should occur, just that it should occur.  I don't think he thinks it matters.  In fact, he calls you a "vag" if you do think it matters:

From the book 5/3/1:

> I don’t care when or how you get this conditioning done, and I don’t
>   care whether it happens on your off days or not. This only time this
>   matters is when you live in the Land of the Vag. Do it when you
>   have time. Make time for it. Just get it done. Nobody ever got strong
>   or got in shape by thinking about it. They did it.

It's worth noting:

> On the deload week, deload! You can still do conditioning work but
>   keep it limited to non-circuits such as Prowler pushing,
>   running/sprinting, etc. Let your body rest.

Personally, when I ran 5/3/1 variants I always drove to a hill immediately after leaving the gym to get some conditioning in (I think this makes more since than doing it immediately before). On off days I'd go to the same hill on my lunch hour from work.  But, as he says, just get it done.  Do it whenever is most convenient for you.

Comment: what do you think to two days conditioning at the weekend?